# C++/Objective-C - how to analyse a big project (Unix way)?

Tags: c++, objective-c, linux, open-source, code-analysis

Normally, to analyse big C projects, I prefer grep/GNU command line tools, [lint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_%28software%29), simple Python scripts. Saying "to analyse" C project I mean to collect code statistics, to understand project's structure, its data structures and flow of execution - what function calls what, entry points in different modules, static members, threads, etc. But it works not so good with an object-oriented code.

Whenever I have a big C++ (or Objective-C) project, containing large number of source files and several directories, I would like to see it's class diagram, data fields, methods, messages, instances, etc.

I am looking for a most [Unix way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_way) solution. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doxygen is the closest i could find, when i was searching last time. It is not unix way, but it is available free for linux/windows/mac. It generated descent graphs for me. Hope it helps.

http://www.doxygen.nl/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen

Answer (score 0):

Your request is for a variety of views, some text-based, some structure based.

You might consider [Understand for C++](http://www.scientifictoolworks.com) which does a mixture of these.  Don't know if it does ObjectiveC.

Our [Source Code Search Engine (SCSE)](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SearchEngine)  is rather more limited, but provides a much faster way to "grep" than grep does. For large code bases this matters.  It will handle multiple languages and dialects.   We don't have an Objective C dialect, but I think our C or C++ front ends would actually work pretty well for this, since Objective C uses pretty much the same lexical syntax.

Answer (score 0):

With message passing and dynamic dispatch going around you are pretty much screwed. It doesn't even depend on language, message is as well used in C++ world. There is no tool that can analyze the code and tell what the application flow will look like. In those cases, the whole data/execution flow may depend on configuration files, how you hook up producers/consumers together etc.. and change significantly. If you are lucky, there would be some high-level documentation, maybe with pictures and description of overall ideas etc. Otherwise, the only option here is to run it under debugger for any given configuration and see what is going on in there, step by step. Isn't that a true UNIX way?